# CS 1061 Error on ASP.NET when doing a Login Button

Tags: c#, asp.net

I got this error --> CS1061: 'aspx_index_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'Login' and no extension method 'Login' accepting a first argument of type 'aspx_index_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have looked for several possible problems, but it still gave me this error:
-I have added a function Login(object sender, EventArgs e) on Code Behind
-The function is protected
-The namespace and class names should have no problem to refer to code behind file

Here's the two files (aspx file and aspx.cs file):
index.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/master/header.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="index.aspx.cs" Inherits="project.aspx.index" %>
<asp:Content runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="css_holder">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="login">
    <form runat="server">
        <h1>SIGN IN</h1>
        <div class="row">
            <asp:TextBox class="input" placeholder="User Name" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder='UserName'" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <asp:TextBox TextMode="Password" class="input" placeholder="Password" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder='Password'" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <div class="row button">
            <asp:Button class="button_design" Text="Login" OnClick="Login" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </form>
</asp:Content>
```

index.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace project.aspx
{
    public partial class index : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Login(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: `Inherits="project.aspx.index"` looks incorrect. The fully qualified name of the `index` class appears to be `project.index`

Comment: It is because I have a sub-folder aspx, which is why I need to have aspx between project and index.

Comment: But that isn't how it is namespaced.  It is the namespace that you need to follow, not the folder structure.  The `inherits` attribute specifies a class name.  It does not use the folder structure for that.

Comment: Since it is not breaking immediately with that namespace, I wouldn't be surprised if you have another `index` class in a `project.aspx` namespace, which does not have the Login method you are expecting. I'd correct the Inherits to `project.index`, and possibly remove an extraneous class.

Comment: I know what's going on now. The main problem is that I forgot to publish the project. Once I published it, it can totally loaded. It may also the Inherit problem as you guys mentioned, but I still suspected this point because the Inherit thing was made by visual studio, not myself. It appears to be 'project.aspx.index' when I make a new webform in an 'aspx' subolder, and to be 'project.index' when I make it right under my project.